# _heroku:2: HEROKU_AC_ANALYTICS_DIR: parameter not set

Tags: heroku, zsh, manjaro, snap

I installed heroku cli via snap (`sudo snap install heroku --classic`), but the autocomplete does not work throws an error: `_heroku:2: HEROKU_AC_ANALYTICS_DIR: parameter not set`, never encountered this before, who knows what could be the problem?

*i`m using the zsh command shell*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-autocomplete

```
heroku update
heroku autocomplete
```

Worked for me.

UPD:
Run the following after commands above (heroku asks to do this after running them anyways):

```
printf "$(heroku autocomplete:script zsh)" >> ~/.zshrc; source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only worked for me after running: ```printf "$(heroku autocomplete:script zsh)" >> ~/.zshrc; source ~/.zshrc``` in the terminal

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what heroku tells you to do after running `heroku autocomplete` :)

Comment: @Gildergun In that case, supplement your answer so that I can count it as "complete"